# Typescript typed Map

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
    export type AvatarSize = "xs" | "sm" | "md";
    
    const sizes = new Map<AvatarSize, 32 | 44 | 104>([
      ["xs", 32],
      ["sm", 44],
      ["md", 104]
    ]);
```

To me, it feels dirty. I wonder if there is any other way to write it without hard-coding the sizes?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details to this question. What does this code does and other things. See [help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ask better questions.

Comment: What does the code do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the array passed into the constructor `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `Array<[string, number]>`, and use generics to look up the key on the constructed map to get the AvatarSize type:

```
const sizes = new Map([
    ["xs", 32],
    ["sm", 44],
    ["md", 104]
] as const);
export type AvatarSize = Parameters<typeof sizes.get>[0];
```

Another way of doing it would be to declare the array outside:

```
const sizesArr = [
    ["xs", 32],
    ["sm", 44],
    ["md", 104]
] as const;
const sizes = new Map(sizesArr);
export type AvatarSize = (typeof sizesArr)[number][0];
```